# How to migrate from Autofac to Microsoft Dependency Injection?

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, autofac

I'm stop to use Autofac and using Microsoft Dependency Injection in my .NET Core 3.1 application.

How can I do the same stuff in DI:

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
    .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IEventHandlerRabbitMq<>))
    .InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterType<BusPublisher>().As<IBusPublisher>().InstancePerDependency();

builder.RegisterInstance(DefaultJaeger.Create())
    .As<ITracer>()
    .SingleInstance()
    .PreserveExistingDefaults();
```

Comment: There is no equivalent to `RegisterAssemblyTypes` in MS.DI. You will have to either register each implementation explicitly, or have to use reflection to find and register all implementations.

Comment: btw, are you aware that you can keep using Autofac in your .NET Core application?

Comment: Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(item => item.GetInterfaces()
            .Where(i => i.IsGenericType).Any(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandlerRabbitMq<>)) && !item.IsAbstract && !item.IsInterface)
            .ToList()

Comment: .ForEach(assignedTypes =>
            {
                var serviceType = assignedTypes.GetInterfaces().First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEventHandlerRabbitMq<>));
                types.Add(assignedTypes);
                
                services.AddScoped(serviceType, assignedTypes);
            });

Comment: Can I using GetExecutingAssembly instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Steven](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264697/steven) says, you need to use reflection for `AsClosedTypesOf`. There is some example how you can implement this:

```
public static void RegisterGenerics(this IServiceCollection services, Assembly assembly, Type genericType)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .FirstOrDefault(a => a.FullName == assembly.FullName)
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(genericType) && !x.IsAbstract && !x.IsInterface)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(t =>
            {
                services.AddTransient(genericType, t);
            });
    }
```

And then you can use it in your startup class:

```
services.RegisterGenerics(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), typeof(IEventHandler<>));
```